# Can't compare datetime.datetime to instancemethod

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm trying to make work this `if` condition in one of my `Django 1.5` project's view:

```
profile = request.user.get_profile()
    if profile.expirationdate < datetime.now():
```

but it raise an error: `can't compare datetime.datetime to instancemethod`.

The `expirationdate` comes from a function in my custom user model:

```
def expirationdate(self):
    expiration = self.premiumactivation + datetime.timedelta(days=self.premiumduration)
    return expiration
```

and returns a `DateTime` object since both `premiumactivation` and `premiumduration` are `DateTime` objects.

Is there any way I can make it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually call the method. The value of `profile.expirationdate` is the method itself, not result of a function call. Try `profile.expirationdate()` instead.